# Is there a way to create promotional code for a subscription through Google API?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

All documentation that I see is referred to Play console, but I need to create a promotional code from my backend. So theres is an API for make this possible?

[Create promo codes for your apps and in-app products in the Google Play Developer Console](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html)